# Is Office Fabric used in creating the Exchange Admin Center? What else is?

Tags: exchange-server, office365-apps, office365connectors, office-fabric

I need to create an administrative portal that is visually consistent with Office 365 and Exchange online / 2016

What UX experience is most similar to the admin portal in these situations?

I discovered [Office Fabric](https://dev.office.com/fabric) but not sure what else is needed to get an Exchange administrator page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office UI Fabric team member here. I'm not sure if Fabric is currently used in the Exchange Admin Portal (I don't think so today), but as Slava points out, Fabric is the framework we use to build many of the apps & experiences throughout Office 365, with many pages and experiences being onboarded all the time. It's your best bet if you want to build a new UX that looks and feels like Office, specifically the [Fabric-React](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/) components, since we stress-test these in our own products and hold them to a very high standard in terms of performance, accessibility, and feature set.

Comment: Thanks. I could  match the azure portal do you know what that could be?

Comment: PS where should I post fabric questions? SO downvoted me, but bootstrap questions exist here....

Comment: I'm also not sure if Azure is using Fabric, though I believe it is in places (I'm officially in the OneDrive & SharePoint team and am not always privvy to what other teams are up to). I can look into this and see if I can find you a good experience to compare to.

Also, I'm not sure why there'd be issues posting Fabric questions here. I've seen quite a few other questions about it, so I'd think you should be fine!

Comment: yes, I would love to hear a response from either group's portal. My goal is to  integrate my Admin console, the Outlook Addin, and Azure marketplace offering as seamlessly as possible. MSFT customers with Azure AD is my target.

Comment: Mind up voting if you (and the SO community) want Fabric SDK questions here? According to the rules, I'm well researched, and on topic.

Comment: Agreed! Done :) Just got enough reputation to be able to upvote. Your goals make total sense--would love to see what you're shooting for that to look like. I'll ask around and follow up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your research is correct. [Office UI Fabric](https://dev.office.com/fabric) is the front-end framework for building experiences that fit seamlessly into Office and Office 365. Mainly the product made to be replicate Office applications (Word, Outlook, etc.) in 3rd party apps and add-ins. It should be suitable for administrative portal as well, but probably not that reach.

Office UI fabric has two mayor parts: One is [Office UI Fabric Core](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core) which includes set of style sheets and the second [Office UI Fabric JS](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js) which delivers built-in components you may use out of box with the core styles.